# How can I prevent everyone from seeing admin user messages in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm attempting to set up a commenting system. The issue I have is that all users are seeing admin comments meant for just one user. If a user submits a ticket and admin respond with a comment, any other user should not be able to view that comment except the user the opened the ticket.

**views**

```
from .models import Support, Comment
from .forms import SupportForm, CommentForm

@login_required
def support_details(request, id):
    support = Support.objects.get(id=id)
    recent_support = Support.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            comment_form = CommentForm()
            messages.success(request, 'comment posted successfully')
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'support': support,
        'recent_support': recent_support,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form
        }
    return render(request, 'support-detail.html', context)
```

**models**

```
from users.models import User
from django.db import models


class Support(models.Model):
    SERVICE_CHOICES = (
        ("Crypto", "Crypto"),
        ("Transaction", "Transaction"),
        ("Others", "Others"),
    )
    support_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    related_service = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=SERVICE_CHOICES, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    is_close = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user', null=True)
    support = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'comment', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}

<div class="mx-auto px-5 md:px-[10em] mt-[2em]">
    <div class="md:grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">
        <div class="col-span-2 mb-8 bg-white drop-shadow border-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-start md:items-center">
                <div class="space-y-2 p-6 md:p-10 grow">
                    <h1 class="text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white">{{support.subject}}</h1>
                    <div class="text-sm">
                        <span class="mr-2  dark:text-white">Ticket System</span> / <span class="ml-2 dark:text-white dark:text-white">Theme not updating in downloads</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if support.is_close == True %}
                <div class="flex justify-center pr-5 pt-7 md:p-10 items-center gap-1.5 grow-0">
                    <div class="w-1 h-1 bg-red-500 p-1 border rounded-full flex"></div><h1 class="text-xs font-bold text-red-500 dark:text-white">CLOSED</h1>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="flex justify-center pr-5 pt-7 md:p-10 items-center gap-1.5 grow-0">
                    <div class="w-1 h-1 bg-blue-500 p-1 border rounded-full flex"></div><h1 class="text-xs font-bold text-blue-500 dark:text-white">OPENED</h1>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center text-center flex-wrap bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                <div class="text-xs md:border-2 h-full p-5 border-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700 space-y-2 w-1/2 md:w-1/4">
                    <h1 class="font-bold text-xs  dark:text-white">TICKET ID</h1>
                    <p class="text-gray-500 text-[1.3em]  dark:text-white">{{support.support_id}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-xs md:border-2 h-full p-5 border-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700 space-y-2 w-1/2 md:w-1/4">
                    <h1 class="font-bold text-xs  dark:text-white">STATUS</h1>
                    {% if support.is_close == True %}
                    <p class="text-gray-500 text-[1.3em]  dark:text-white">Closed</p>
                    {% else %}
                    <p class="text-gray-500 text-[1.3em]  dark:text-white">Open</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="text-xs md:border-2 h-full p-5 border-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700 space-y-2 w-1/2 md:w-1/4">
                    <h1 class="font-bold text-xs  dark:text-white">DATE</h1>
                    <p class="text-gray-500 text-[1.3em]  dark:text-white">{{support.created_at|date:'d-m-Y'}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-xs md:border-2 h-full p-5 border-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700 space-y-2 w-1/2 md:w-1/4">
                    <h1 class="font-bold text-xs  dark:text-white">SERVICE</h1>
                    <p class="text-gray-500 text-[1.3em]  dark:text-white">{{support.related_service}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="md:grid grid-cols-4 p-10">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{support.user.profile.profile_image.url}}" class="w-[7em] h-[7em] mb-3 md:w-[7em] md:h-[7em] rounded-full object-cover" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-3">
                    <h1 class="mb-2  dark:text-white">{{support.user.first_name}} {{support.user.last_name}}</h1>
                    <h1 class="text-gray-500 text-sm mb-5  dark:text-white">{{support.created_at}}</h1>
                    <p class="dark:text-white">
                        {{support.message}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> 
            {% for comment in comments %}
            
            <div class="md:grid grid-cols-4 p-10">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{comment.user.profile.profile_image.url}}" class="w-[7em] h-[7em] mb-3 md:w-[7em] md:h-[7em] rounded-full object-cover" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-3">
                    <h1 class="mb-2  dark:text-white">{{comment.user.first_name}} {{comment.user.last_name}}</h1>
                    <h1 class="text-gray-500 text-sm mb-5  dark:text-white">{{comment.created_at}}</h1>
                    <p class="dark:text-white">
                        {{comment.comment}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


            {% endfor %}
            <form action="" method="post"> 
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="px-[3em] space-y-7 mb-[5em]">              
                    <label for="message" class="block mb-2 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">Your message</label>
                    <!-- <input id="message" type="text" class="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-sm border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Leave a comment..."></input> -->
                    {{comment_form.comment | add_class:"block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-sm border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"}}
                    <div class="">
                        <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 rounded-sm text-sm w-full md:w-[12em] md:float-right px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-[5em] md:mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Submit a Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white pb-10 mb-10 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-900">
            <div class="border border-b-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
                <h1 class="px-10 py-5 text-xl text-gay-800  dark:text-gray-200">Recent Tickets</h1>
            </div>
            {% for support in recent_support %}
            <div class="pl-10 pr-10 pt-10 space-y-4">
                <p class="mb-2 hover:text-blue-500  dark:text-gray-200"><a href="{% url 'support:support-detail' support.id %}">{{support.subject}}</a></p>
                <p class="text-gray-500">{{support.created_at}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <!-- <div class="pl-10 pr-10 pt-10 space-y-4">
                <p class="mb-2 hover:text-blue-500  dark:text-gray-200"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, dolorem.</a></p>
                <p class="text-gray-500  dark:text-gray-200">6 Sep 2018</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pl-10 pr-10 pt-10 space-y-4">
                <p class="mb-2 hover:text-blue-500  dark:text-gray-200"><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, dolorem.</a></p>
                <p class="text-gray-500  dark:text-gray-200">6 Sep 2018</p>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  {% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Support, Comment


class SupportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Support
        fields = [
            'subject',
            'email',
            'related_service',
            'message',
            'is_close'
        ]

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'comment'
        ]
```

Comment: So what's the issue you don't want to show admin messages to other users or you want to show it to all users ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari This is a support ticket system. If a user opened a ticket, Admin response should be viewed by the admin and the user that opened the ticket only but currently, admin response to a users ticket is been viewed by every user on the platform which is what i am trying to prevent.

Comment: Do you want to show user comments to other users?

Comment: No. Only to the intended user